# Function of date and time in the 6ª column automatically

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to improve my function I need a way to insert a date and time in the 6ª column automatically.

```
function processForm(formObject){
var url="my url";
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Requisição");

ws.appendRow([
formObject.c1,
formObject.c2,
formObject.c3,
formObject.c4,
formObject.c5,]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want a hard-coded timestamp in your routine? There [is all kinds of documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) related dates in javaScript. I think this would work, you just might want to format the syntax.

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "my url";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Requisição");
  var aDate = new Date();

  ws.appendRow([
    formObject.c1,
    formObject.c2,
    formObject.c3,
    formObject.c4,
    formObject.c5,
    aDate]);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the documentation, i put this "new Date(),]);" and worked!

Comment: You know a function to get the email? Thx again!

Comment: Yes you could put the new date directly in the code. I prefer to create variables in advance to allow for clearer debugging.  I don't know what you mean by get the email.

Comment: I found. "Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()," 